# Chrome App: Getting a list of files in a designated folder

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am building a chrome app for Digital Signage where I need the user to select some files from a particular folder (preferably in the app's directory) i.e audio, videos, photos which should be created by the app on install.

The sample code provided by Google requires that the user navigates to a folder like this

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(theEntry) {
  if (!theEntry) {
    output.textContent = 'No Directory selected.';
    return;
  }
  // use local storage to retain access to this file
  chrome.storage.local.set({'chosenFile': chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(theEntry)});
  loadDirEntry(theEntry);
});
```

However, my app simply needs the name of files in that (say Video) known directory for the user to build a playlist, rather than actually selecting a video file.

Is this supported in chrome.fileSystem API? Any pointers to how I cold get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using either the app's sandboxed file systems, or the app's install folder itself.

The sandboxed file systems allow the app to store whatever data it wants, in whatever structure it wants. There are two to choose from: persistent or temporary. Temporary may be cleared at any point in time. To use these check out [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). Some of its code may be out of date with the spec. Note also apps need to request the `unlimitedStorage` to use these.

The install folder itself can be used in a read only way. To do this you use [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry).